# Microsoft programs no internet when connected to VPN

Tags: windows, vpn, microsoft-office, nas, microsoft-edge

I came across a somewhat strange problem from my point of view.

The setup is as followed:

1. There is a NAS which runs 1 program that need to be accessible from different locations.
2. There is VPN running on the NAS.

Now when I connect to the VPN network I can ping and browsing works fine but only with Google Chrome. Edge does not work which is not that big of a problem but Microsoft Outlook does not work either.

I have been playing around with DNS settings and tried some different local and external DNS servers. Nothing seems to be resolving this issue.

How should I approach this problem and fix the desired outcome?

P.S. preferably without going to the NAS, it's not impossible but just difficult because of the distance.

Comment: You can ping the network, which means vpn no problem, you should check the internal network. We need to use vpn to connect to exchange servers, you can try using the internal company DNS.

Comment: Could you explain a bit further? I used the DNS IP from the company gateway where the NAS is installed but still only Google Chrome worked.